# Polipo startup Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, tor

My Polipo service would start automatically when I installed it but after I installed Stacer and cleaned Ubuntu, Polipo won't start after boot.

I remember the first time after running Polipo manually I got some error like this:

```
Couldn't open log file /var/log/polipo/polipo.log: No Such File or Directory
```

then I created `/var/log/polipo` folder manually and it worked perfectly but it won't start after boot automatically.

I event tried to add it to startup application and when I do

```bsh
ps aux | grep polipo
root      5885  0.0  0.0  14200  4376 pts/0    S+   00:29   0:00 sudo polipo
```

but no connection from Polipo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have write access to the log file

Comment: you are right, permission for folder hadn't write for user. thanks